# Login with php refresh when I click at the button

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create an instagram replic login with HTML and PHP.
I create the HTML5 and css. The problem is when I did the php part...
I open the page in firefox, write the username and password as user - password and the page makes a refresh.
My success.php has a line code: `<h2> Gracias por trabajar con nosotros!</h2>`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<?php
    session_start();

    $username = "user";
    $password = "password";
    if (isset($_SESSION['Login']) && $_SESSION['Login'] == true) {
        header("Location: success.php");
    }

    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        if ($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password){
            $_SESSION['Login'] = true;
            header("Location: success.php");
        }
    }
?>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Overpass+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
</head>

    <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="main-content">
          <div class="header">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/zqpwkLQ.png" />
          </div>
          <div class="l-part">
            <form method="post" action="index.php">
              <input name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" class="input-1" />
              <input name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" class="input-2"/>
              <input name="Login"  type="submit" value="Login" class="btn" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line:

```
header("Location: success.php");
```

The page will reload itself after the POST.

Comment: didnt work! if I remove it the page reload itself too. I need to go to success.php

Comment: Your requirement contradicts the demand to reload the page... since Web 2.0 it is even questionable, why you even want to switch the page. Just look around on the web, you'll might find it difficult to get a login success page displayed, wherever you may login.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo '<script>window.location.replace("/success.php");</script>';
```

Rather than:
`header("Location: success.php");`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are already sending output with `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` and AFTER that trying to edit headers. You can only edit headers (or redirect) BEFORE you send any output. 
So put that line after your PHP script before `<html>` tag.

If you want to keep that line, use `die('<head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=success.php"></head>');` instead of header. `die()` halts execution of script and exits so it is better suited for your login page rather than `echo()`